# traversing nth level in the lightning tree

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

i  am trying to create account contact hierarchy in the `lightning:tree`  and identifying nth level and creating tree like nested tree structure.

```
parent account
                 contact1
                 contact2
                 child account1
                          contact3
                          contact4
                           childaccount2 
                            contact5
                            contact6
```

it is creating tree on same levels

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It pretty much spells it out for you. I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/32bd056260cf4850ba15bc5641b6c42f) that demonstrates how to build a nested tree.

Comment: @sfdx fox i read the documentation seen the gist(which is using custom component c:treenode)i am trying use the lightning:tree to achieve nested trees the problem i am facing is:lightning:tree allow only standard attribute like label,name,expanded,items and i can achieve flat structure like account with contact not the inner nested tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting the code I wrote in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/32bd056260cf4850ba15bc5641b6c42f), you simply need to build the nested tree. Here's an example I wrote up, now also available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/0d26e0b9e612a235c7a4b84a86397113):

## Apex Code

```
public class q216767 {
    @AuraEnabled public static Account[] getRecords() {
        return [SELECT Name, ParentId, (SELECT Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account];
    }
}
```

## Application

```
<aura:application controller="q216767" extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="List" default="[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:tree header="Accounts" items="{!v.data}" />
</aura:application>
```

## Controller

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getRecords");
        action.setCallback(this, result => helper.parse(component, result));
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

## Helper

```
({
    parse: function(component, result) {
        var accounts = result.getReturnValue(),
            parents = { undefined: { items: [] }};
        accounts.forEach(account => parents[account.Id] = { items: [], name: account.Id, label: "Account: "+account.Name, expanded: false});
        accounts.forEach(account => { if(account.Contacts) { account.Contacts.forEach(contact => parents[account.Id].items.push({items: [], name: contact.Id, label: "Contact: "+contact.Name, expanded: false}))}});
        accounts.forEach(account => parents[account.ParentId].items.push(parents[account.Id]));
        component.set("v.data", parents[undefined].items);
    }
})
```

Comment: you nailed it.thanks it works perfect for parallel childs also.